# Iterate through database and iterate certain values pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has the following columns.

```
╔════╦══════╦═════════╗
║ id ║ year ║ quarter ║
╠════╬══════╬═════════╣
║  1 ║ 2018 ║       3 ║
║  1 ║ 2018 ║       4 ║
║  2 ║ 2018 ║       1 ║
║  2 ║ 2018 ║       2 ║
║  3 ║ 2018 ║       4 ║
╚════╩══════╩═════════╝
```

Expected Ouput:

```
╔════╦══════╦═════════╗
║ id ║ year ║ quarter ║
╠════╬══════╬═════════╣
║  1 ║ 2018 ║       3 ║
║  1 ║ 2018 ║       4 ║
║  1 ║ 2019 ║       1 ║
║  2 ║ 2018 ║       1 ║
║  2 ║ 2018 ║       2 ║
║  3 ║ 2018 ║       4 ║
║  3 ║ 2019 ║       1 ║
╚════╩══════╩═════════╝
```

I want to iterate over the table and if the last quarter in each id is 4, i want to add 1 to the year and make the quarter 1. Here is the following code i tried

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if df['quarter'] is 4:
       df['quarter'] = 1
       df['year'] = df['year'] + 1
```

Im pretty new to pandas and python so if anyone has any suggestions that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can build a new `df`, build your logic, and `append`

```
df2 = df.loc[df.quarter.eq(4)].copy()
df2['year'], df2['quarter'] = df2['year'].add(1), 1
df.append(df2).sort_values(by='id')

    id  year    quarter
0   1   2018    3
1   1   2018    4
1   1   2019    1
2   2   2018    1
3   2   2018    2
4   3   2018    4
4   3   2019    1
```

Or, in want a one-liner

```
df.append(df.loc[df.quarter.eq(4)].assign(year=df.year.add(1), quarter=1)).sort_values(by='id')
```